# Powerbi Report: Filter "Opportunities" by "Contains Product X" and/ or "Does not Contain Product X"

Tags: powerbi

I want to allow my users to filter opportunities by "Products Included" and "Products Not Included".

My data source looks like this: (simplified version)
Table "Opportunities":

```
Opp ID, Product
1, Product A
1, Product B
2, Product B
3, Product A
3, Product C
```

Table "Products": (There is a relationship to " 'Opps'[Product] " that allows filtering already)

```
Product
Product A
Product B
Product C
```

I can also easily convert the source to look like:

```
Opp ID, Product A, Product B, Product C
1, True, True, False
2, False, True, False
3, True, False, True
```

My most common user question is:
"Show me all Opportunities that contain Product A, but NOT Product C"

Any Idea how I could approach this?

Comment: You could create a powerquery m dataset which joins onto each record. Then you could just use a splicer or list of toggles to choose what you want. Or do you just want something in DAX

Comment: @Monofuse I would be thankful for any (ideally best practice) approach. Happy to put in the work, but lacking a pattern / concept / strategy  to apply here.